# how to add body Filters in PHP API Curl

Tags: php, api

I need to add BODY content with some filters in my PHP CODE of APi curl How can i do it

I need to be added in my API call

Here is API CAll Code

```
$chn = curl_init();
curl_setopt($chn, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($chn, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.livechatinc.com/v3.4/agent/action/list_archives');
curl_setopt($chn, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($chn, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{}');
curl_setopt($chn, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token
    )
);
```

Comment: _"I need to add BODY content with some filters"_ - What body content? What do you mean by "filters"? Please add some more details to your question. Remember that we're not there with you, most likely have no idea what that API is/how it works and have no idea what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
$parameters = array( "key1" => val1, "key2" => val2);

# your curl definition

curl_setopt($chn, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you edit your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a request body to your API call by passing the data as a string in the **CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS** option.

```
$filter = array(
"page" => 1,
"page_size" => 20,
"start_time" => "2022-01-01T00:00:00Z",
"end_time" => "2022-12-31T23:59:59Z",
"sort_by" => "start_time",
"sort_order" => "asc"
);

$chn = curl_init();
curl_setopt($chn, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($chn, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.livechatinc.com/v3.4/agent/action/list_archives');
curl_setopt($chn, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($chn, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($filter));
curl_setopt($chn, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token
)
);
```